# Pegar conteudo dentro do iframe

Tags: javascript, angular

Ola,

Utilizo Angular 8.

Preciso pegar o conteudo de dentro do iframe:

O próprio iframe me mostra no console isto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não se como faço para pegar a informação de dentro dele...

IFRAME

```html
<iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="400" src="https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget?Languages=CSharp&amp;projectType=Console&amp;Compiler=Net45&amp;CSharp_CodeBlock=using%20System%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%0Apublic%20class%20Classe%20%0A%7B%0A%09public%20double%20Executar%28%29%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20Escreva%20o%20c%C3%B3digo%20aqui%0A%09%7D%0A%7D" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**EDIT**

Sei que foge da pergunta inicial, mas pensando em ajudar a comunidade deixo uma solução sem iframe para o que eu precisava que era um editor de codigo dentro da minha aplicação, e como nao conhecia outras formas de se fazer, achei que nao existisse algo direcionado para isto.

Pesquisando, eu encontrei o [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/).

Comment: Portanto nao é possivel?